# I am facing a problem while running my python file in PyCharm or VS Code. Error:Process finished with exit code 139(interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: segmentation-fault

[image: Please check this image]# This is the problem

## Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

OS: macOS Monterey
Version: 12.4
Chip: Apple M2

I have tried re-installing python, recreated the .py file, restarted device but it did not work

I am facing this problem only when I am using pyttsx3